# Why does REST API response contain the bean name?

Tags: java, json, api, rest, response

I need a response like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "site": "Google",
        "name": "abc",
        "value": "111",
        "level": "BASE",
        "character": "&"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "site": "Yahoo",
        "name": "xyz",
        "value": "222",
        "level": "ONE",
        "character": ";"
    }
]
```

---

Instead, this is the response I get:

```
{
    "responseObjects": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "site": "Google",
                "name": "abc",
                "value": "111",
                "level": "BASE",
                "character": "&"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "site": "Yahoo",
                "name": "xyz",
                "value": "222",
                "level": "ONE",
                "character": ";"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

---

My Response class has the following member:

```
private final List<Object> responseObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();

public List<Object> getResponseObjects() {
    return responseObjects;
}

public void addToResponseObjects(Object responseObject) {
    responseObjects.add(responseObject);
}
```

---

And in my Resource class I have this code that returns the response:

```
List<MyBean> responseList = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
.....
.....
.....
response.addToResponseObjects(responseList);
return response;
```

---

What changes would I need to do to not have "responseObjects" get added in the response? I only need to have the JSON String/Array in the response.

Comment: What are you using to serialize your object?

Comment: No, what are you using to transform your objects into JSON?

Comment: Why don't you just send the list then, instead of the response?